# APEX Oracle PDF generating on table

Tags: oracle, pdf-generation, oracle-apex

In my base is prepared table with data required on invoices. But I don't know how to generate them in PDF files.

Solution should prepare the model with precisely located fields with data (placement on A4 page format) dynamic - from table and static - once set up in invoice model. And should work with repports. I imagine it as button in last collumn in repport with rows that contain collumns describing the order - client date invoice number etc.  I prefer Free tools. If it's possible, simple to use and install.

My database is Oracle Express Edition 11g, Apex ver 4.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

We use that exact configuration. We have a web service call which delivers XML with XSLT style sheet reference to RenderX's cloudformatter. Their WSDL is http://www.cloudformatter.com:6577/fairy?WSDL which would self configure the web service once you create it in Apex. Like below:[image: APEX Cloudformatter Params]

We use PL_SQL to generate the XML from the database. Cloudformatter SOAP takes in the FO File argument which can by XML with XSL link to transform or it can be XSL FO. Cloudformatter also has a REST interface which could be used and you would even use raw XML and style with css to format HTML5 and css via Javascript.